# How to read an xml file with & sign

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

This is my `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE papers>
<papers>
  <paper>
    <title>Title containing & and more</title>
  </paper>
</papers>
```

How do I read that using `lxml`'s `etree`? I tried

```
from lxml import etree

with open(xml_file, 'r') as inf:
    tree = etree.parse(inf)
```

but it results in the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69955)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102257)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1789, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102516)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1684, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101442)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1134, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97069)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 5, column 30
```

Comment: I ran your XML file through **xmllint** and got error right at the ampersand. That means your XML is malformed.

Comment: Escape it with `&amp;`

Comment: I can't change the file.

Comment: @MERose, ...the file is **wrong**. As written right now, it is not valid XML, and thus not truly an "XML file". File a bug with whichever software created it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to retain the `&` character, you can parse the file as HTML.

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.parse(path)
```

If you *don't* need the `&` character, you can create a new XML parser and pass the `recover=True` option.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse(path, parser=parser)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the xml file is malformed, because of the [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) (predefined xml entity) use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) if you can. It is a more error tolerant parser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find("title").text
```

outputs

```
Title containing & and more
```